# Excel pivot table Dates and Amounts

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that includes separate data columns for clients and the bonds that they hold.

In following columns are the dates on which those bonds will pay interest in the future and (i.e. payment date 1, payment date 2, etc.) and the actual amount of interest to be received (i.e. payment amount 1, payment amount 2, etc.)

I would like to create a pivot table that lists the clients and their individual holdings of bonds in columns.  Along the top I would like to have a list of all future interest dates and the body of the table would include the amounts to be received on those dates.  I have included a simple example below.

```
Client A     June 30   July 31   August 31  September 30
  Bond 1     1,000                           1,000
  Bond 2     1,000     1,000     1,000       1,000

Client B
   Bond 2    2,000     2,000      2,000      2,000
   Bond 3              1,000      1,000
```

I can easily set-up the columns on the left but I am unable to create a header row that provides the simple picture above.  Help!?

Thank you.

Phil

Comment: The " simple example below" .. is the raw input data or the desired output? (I think others need both to replicate your case..)

Comment: Client  Bond  Date 1 Date 2 Date 3 Date 4 Pmt 1 Pmt 2 Pmt 3 Pmt 4                           A         1         6/30     9/30                           1000   1000                                            A         2         6/30     7/31    8/31    9/30      1000  1000  1000   1000                      B         2         6/30     7/31    8/31    9/30      2000   2000  2000   2000                          B         3         7/31     8/31                            1000   1000

Comment: The above is a representation of the desired output.  The source data with headers would appear as follows..

Comment: I'm sorry the data input view did not present well.  The picture at the top is my representation of the desired output.  However, the data I have exists currently in columns.  The data for Client A, bond 1 would be shown in distinct columns.  I will include commas as the delimiters.  Client A, bond 1, June 30, Sep 30, , , 1000, 1000, , ,  This data would correspond to the column headers:  Client, Bond, PayDate1,  PayDate2, PayDate3, PayDate4, Pmnt1, Pmnt2, Pmnt3, Pmnt4

Comment: please edit the question and include the additional info. (you can highlight the pasted data (during editing) , then press Ctrl+K to convert it into the 'grayed'/code format as above)

Answer (score 0):

I can easily solve the problem about PIVOT but I have not understood the requirements exactly.
I also dont know whether I can send you the Excel File through e-mail or not. As I am not aware about this.
Thanks.